# Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 24.2.1'

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I'm Trying do Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView (version 24.2.1) download, but the message below is displayed:

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 24.2.1'. You
>   are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

How can I update the `MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0`? How specifically does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, error says that **Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 24.2.1** does not contain assembly for **MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0**.

So **Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 24.2.1** needs to be updated.

To Fix you problem - your app needs to have its Target Framework set to Android 7.0 (API Level 24) or higher to install it.

You can change it in **Project Options -> General -> Target Framework**.